# Traceback.py tries to compare int and 'limit' which resolves to an ImportError

Tags: python, lettuce, python-2to3

I'm trying to get [lettuce](http://lettuce.it/index.html) to run on python 3, and it's not been working. So I quickly [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)'d all the offending files, and now I get this issue:

When handling not finding terrain, lettuce crashes out due to this line

```
sys.stderr.write(exceptions.traceback.format_exc(e))
```

Which is due to this:

```
   while curr is not None and (limit is None or n < limit):
```

Limit is an `ImportError` and cannot be compared to n, which an `int`!

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of `def format_exc(limit=None, chain=True):` in python3 means you *have* to specify the kwarg of e, in your error:

```
sys.stderr.write(exceptions.traceback.format_exc(e))
```

Must be  (by elimination)

```
sys.stderr.write(exceptions.traceback.format_exc(chain=e))
```

The call was assuming that `e` corresponded to the first kwarg of `limit`

Comment: Actually, you don't need to pass the `e` argument (if that's an exception itself, as it usually is) to format_exc() at all. See here https://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html

Comment: @sm4rk0 I don't see anything in their that indicates that.

Comment: `format_exc` takes two optional parameters: `limit` (default=None) and `chain` (default=True). None of them is of `Exception` type. Try it without the arguments.

Comment: @sm4rk0 I did, see my question. It may have changed across versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (no `e` argument):

```
sys.stderr.write(exceptions.traceback.format_exc())
```